# Filter Gmail spam messages from faked addresses

Tags: filter, dns, gmail, spam

For a while now I am fighting with a lot of spam messages which addresses seem faked, but I hope a good thing is they have a pattern...they all look like this:

```
@flight134msgs.gdn
@flight491msgs.gdn
@flight132msgs.gdn
```

and

```
@sunmail780msg.gdn
@sunmail604msg.gdn
@sunmail423msg.gdn
```

Now, is there a way to filter them by their domain name, or even better, only by that `.gdn` part.

I have tried:

```
label:spam .gdn
```

and

```
.gdn
```

and

```
from:(.gdn)
```

but none of the above filter works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

- You can filter messages that contain a piece of specific text.
  In your case, you can put the domains as the text.
  Choose "Has the words" when creating the filters, and type the domains.

[image: screenshot]

- I'd leave out "@" signs, just to be sure the filter finds text properly (for example, some special characters [don't work](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&safe=active&q=what+%3F%40+time+%40+is+%25+sunset+%3F+) in Google Search). Of course that's optional.
- As you suggested, you can make a single filter for emails containing "gdn", but I **would not**. What if someone meant to say "goodnight" or similar? Better to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter these emails out by adding a wildcard after the @

ie.  in the FROM: field from Google Filters type: @*.gdn

I chose to send these all to delete.  Worked like a champ.

Cheers